# How to send multipart-data video file from NextJS frontend to Express backend?

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to enable a user to upload a video file and send it through my NextJS api to my Express backend (and store it in an S3 bucket, I don't have a need to save it on my server), but cannot figure out how to do it after days of searching. I understand that NextJS has a limitation where it cannot read multipart form data, but I don't understand how to strategically address this issue. I have seen packages like `multer` and `formidable`, but I am unsure how to use them (since they seem to be for the backend, and I am having trouble passing the file to my frontend API).

Since the video files can be big, I *think* I need to upload the video files to s3 directly from the frontend (using a multipart upload) and then send the AWS URL for the video to the backend. If this is the right approach, how do I do that?

Project setup: NextJS frontend running on `port 3000` + Express backend server running on `port 5000`.  Here is my code:

FileUpload.tsx (frontend)

```
...
    <div>
      <div>
        { 
          previewURL != null ? 
            file.type.includes("video") ?
              <video id="video" width="800" controls>
                <source src={ previewURL } id="videoSrc" />
              </video> 
            : 
              <audio id="audio" controls>
                <source src={ previewURL } id="audioSrc" />
              </audio> 
          : null
        }

        <form action="/api/uploadToAssemblyAi" method="post">
          <label htmlFor="file">File</label>
          <input
            type="file"
            id="file"
            name="file"
            onChange={ generatePreview }
          />

          <button type="submit"> Upload </button>
          <button type="reset" onChange={ clearFile }> Clear </button>
        </form>
        
      </div>
    </div>
...
```

/api/uploadToAssemblyAi.tsx (frontend)

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import axios from "axios"

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}

export async function uploadData(file: File) {

  // Prep to send file to backend
  const BACKEND_API_URL = process.env.BACKEND_URL
  const assembly = axios.create({
    baseURL: BACKEND_API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  
  // Add file to request
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", file);

  // Call backend
  const { data } = await assembly.post(`${BACKEND_API_URL}/api/synthesize/transcribe}`, formData)
  const transcriptionId = data.transcriptionId

  return transcriptionId
}

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<any>) {
  
  const file = req.body.file
// ^^^ This is not working, I cannot access the file from the form (this is for communication purposes, I know this isn't the right way to do it)
  
  try {
    const transcriptionId = await uploadData(file)
    return res.status(201).redirect(307, `/calls/${transcriptionId}`)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: " + err)
    return res.status(400).send( { msg: err })
  }
}
```

uploadController.ts (backend)

```
...
// This is where I want to receive the file to upload to AWS
export async function transcribeController(req: Request, res: Response) {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
      return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'No files were uploaded.' });
    }
    const file = req.files
    const file = req.body
    // ^^^ I'm not sure how to access the file on the backend since I cannot even send it from the frontend (this is for communication purposes, I know this isn't the right way to do it)

    return
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormData` to send the request. This will be sent as a `multipart/form-data` request.

```
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', file);

 const response = await fetch('/api/uploadToAssemblyAi', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData,
 });
```

You can also update your `form` element to specify that content type:

```
<form
   action="/api/uploadToAssemblyAi"
   method="post"
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is different (besides the enctype) from what I am already doing? Where would the formdata code that you wrote go?

In /api/upload.tsx I am using this FormData approach, but the issue is that `file` is undefined (it seems like the file data is not being passed from my form in FileUpload.tsx to the handler in /api/upload.tsx

Comment: When I add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the form and go into the handler in `/api/upload.tsx`, req.body is undefined

Comment: "req.body is undefined" -> form-data is not a regular `POST` request with a body. You need to use a middleware like `formidable` or `multer` to parse it.

Comment: Can I use those in the nextjs frontend api? I have only seen them used in the express backend

Comment: No on the front end you just need to do what I showed in my answer. Send a `multipart/form-data` request. In express backend you will use a middleware to handle the parsing and `req` object will have the uploaded files